# CSS styles to superimpose Previous and Next buttons on top of photo

Tags: css, button

I looked for similar questions, but didn't find any. Maybe I didn't type the right words.

I need to place 2 transparent buttons on top of a photo in a photo gallery.
On the left middle there will be `<-` and on the right middle there will be `->` image buttons.

These buttons will be my gallery navigation buttons.

Anyone has some tips or code snippet to share?

I have a .NET 4.0 app and I am using jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: thirtydot, thanks for updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the links and the image inside a `div` element with `position: relative;`. Give the links `position: absolute;` and adjust their position accordingly with the `top`, `left`, `right` and or `bottom` properties.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a z-index of 2 in the *style* tag of the buttons? This will move the buttons on top of the photo.